# Proof that something is a sigma-field

Tags: measure-theory

[image]

For the first inclusion I have :

C = {$(H \cap A) \cup (H^c \cap B)$} $\subset$ $A \cup B$ $\subset$ $F \cup {H}$ $\subset$ $\sigma(F \cup${H})

For the first inclusion can I say A U B is subset of F U {H} ? because A,B $\in$ F,but A U B range over F that is A U B = F,but this sets of sets makes me somewhat confused ! any help would be good.

Comment: For the reverse inclusion, you need to show that the collection $\mathcal C$ is a $\sigma$-field. If you can, it would prove that $\mathcal C$ is a $\sigma$-field containing $\mathcal F \cup \{H\}$ and thus $\sigma( \mathcal F \cup \{H\}) \subseteq \mathcal C$ since $\sigma( \mathcal F \cup \{H\})$ is the smallest $\sigma$-field containing $\mathcal F \cup \{H\}$ with respect to inclusion

Comment: Is my first inclusion correct ? For the second inclusion I did everything but I can't get the proof of closed under complement !

Comment: Oh sorry, by first inclusion, I thought you mean $A \cup B \in \mathcal F \cup H$, which I don't think is necessarily true.

Comment: For the “easy” inclusion, you must show that an arbitrary element of $\mathcal{C}$ is an element of $\sigma(\mathcal{F}\cup\{H\})$. An arbitrary element of $\mathcal{C}$ is $S=(H\cap A)\cup(H^c\cap B)$, where $A$ and $B$ are elements of $\mathcal{F}$. By definition, $\sigma(\mathcal{F}\cup\{H\})$ contains $A$ and $B$ as elements (as they are elements of $\mathcal{F}$); it also contains $H$ as an element, explicitly given. Furthermore, $\sigma(\mathcal{F}\cup\{H\})$ is a $\sigma$-field (again by definition), so is closed under complement and countable union and intersection, so it contains $S$.

Comment: I see makes sense thank you.

Comment: Glad to have helped. It can be very hard to discuss both sets and sets of subsets at the same time, and mathematicians unfortunately use words like “contains” to mean two different things: contains as an element (membership) and contains as a subset (inclusion). Little details like the fact that the empty set is *both* an element and a subset of any $\sigma$-field don’t help, either!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot say that $(A\cup B)\subseteq (\mathcal{F}\cup\{H\})$. The phrase “$A$ and $B$ range over $\mathcal{F}$” does not mean what you think. $A$ and $B$ do not represent specific sets, and this phrase does not mean that the union of $A$ and $B$ equals $\mathcal{F}$. It helps describe the definition of $\mathcal{C}$ by explaining what $A$ and $B$ are in that definition.

The sentence

“Let $\mathcal{C}$ denote the sets of the form $(H\cap A)\cup(H^c\cap B)$, where $A$ and $B$ range over $\mathcal{F}$”

means

“Let $\mathcal{C}=\{S\in2^\Omega \mbox{ such that }S=(H\cap A)\cup(H^c\cap B) \mbox{ for some } A,B\in\mathcal{F}\}$.”

The author might have bit a tiny bit clearer to say “Let $\mathcal{C}$ denote *the collection of sets* of the form...”

Comment: So the reason its a subset is according to the following: according to the definition of sigma field F$\cup${H} $\in$ $\sigma$(F$\cup${H}) and by that we can see that C is subset of $\sigma$(F$\cup${H}) right?

Comment: No. $\mathcal{F}\cup\{H\}$ is not an *element* of $\sigma(\mathcal{F}\cup\{H\})$. It is a subset. $\sigma(X)$ is the smallest collection of sets that contains $X$ (as a subcollection) and that is a $\sigma$-field. Try to keep straight which things in the picture are subsets of $\Omega$ and which are *collections of* subsets of $\Omega$. (The latter things are subsets of $2^\Omega$). Using the word collection instead of the word set in the latter case may help.